# How to build a strong type container in Obj-C?

Tags: objective-c

I'm building a class XXTreeNode:

```
@interface XXTreeNode : NSObject<XXSearching>

@property XXTreeNode *parent;
@property NSMutableArray *children;
@property id data;  // problem here
@property(readonly) int count;

-(XXTreeNode*)initWithData: (id)data;
-(bool)addChild: (XXTreeNode*)child;
-(bool)removeSelf;
-(NSArray*)searchChildren: (id)content;  // problem here
-(XXTreeNode*)searchChildrenFirst: (id)content;  // problem here

@end
```

I want this class be generic -- I can store any types in 'data' field. In C#, I can do this easily with

```
class Node<T>
```

then I can create such class with any type I want:

```
Node<String> a = new Node<String>();
Node<int> b = new Node<int>();
```

But how to do such thing in Objective-C?

BTW: I know there is a 'id' type and you can see I already declare the fields I want to be generic as 'id', but 'id' is not suitable for simple types like NSInteger or unichar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

id works fine for primitive types if you box them in NSValue (for structs) or NSNumber (for integral and float types). I have to recommend against using Objective-C generics, it depends on macros, and makes the code confusing.

Unfortunately you won't get type checking if you use simple id values. But keep in mind that generics (real ones in languages that support them) could be thought of as just a way to auto-generate custom subclasses tailored to the particular types in question. You can always write those classes yourself, e.g.

```
@interface IntNode : Node
@property int intData;
@end

@interface Node (IntSearching)
- (NSArray *)searchChildrenForInt:(int)anInt;
-(XXTreeNode*)searchChildrenForFirstInt:(int)anInt;
@end
```

You could implement it something like this:

```
@implementation IntNode
- (int)intData { return [_data intValue]; }
- (void)setIntData:(int)anInt { self.data = @(anInt); }
@end

@implementation Node (IntSearching)
- (NSArray *)searchChildrenForInt:(int)anInt {
    return [self searchChildren:@(anInt)];
}
-(XXTreeNode*)searchChildrenForFirstInt:(int)anInt {
    return [self searchChildrenFirst:@(anInt)];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> but `id` is not suitable for simple types like `NSInteger` or `unichar`.

That's what `NSValue` ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValue_Class/Reference/Reference.html)) and its `NSNumber` subclass ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html)) have been invented for.

Answer (score 1):

Tomer Shiri created exactly this, only a couple of weeks ago so it is still quite new, might be worth [checking out](https://github.com/tomersh/Objective-C-Generics). (https://github.com/tomersh/Objective-C-Generics)

If you want to store numbers, you will need to use [NSNumber](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) which is a wrapper for numeric data-types